# Rails self-referential association join conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the following database schema and models, which constitute a self-referential association where a `Phrase` has many translations of other `Phrase`s, through the `Translation` association:

**Schema**:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151003213732) do

  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "phrases", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "language"
    t.string   "text"
  end

  create_table "translations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "source_id"
    t.integer  "destination_id"
  end
end
```

**Phrase**:

```
class Phrase < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many    :translations,
                class_name: "Translation",
                foreign_key: "source_id"
    has_many    :destination_phrases,
                through: :translations
    has_many    :inverse_translations,
                class_name: "Translation",
                foreign_key: "destination_id"
    has_many    :source_phrases,
                through: :inverse_translations

    enum language: [:eng, :spa, ...]
end
```

**Translation**:

```
class Translation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :source_phrase,
                class_name: "Phrase",
                foreign_key: "source_id"
    belongs_to  :destination_phrase,
                class_name: "Phrase",
                foreign_key: "destination_id"
end
```

Now, I want to run queries based on *source* language and *destination* language. For example, I want to find *English* phrases and their respective *Spanish* translations. Currently I am querying phrases based on *source* language, but then I have to filter out the results using the `select` method on the destination language. What I have looks like the following:

```
@translations = Translation.includes(:source_phrase, :destination_phrase)
                           .where(phrases: {language: @source_language})

# Select only destination phrases where the language matches
@translations = @translations.select {
    |t| t.destination_phrase.language == @destination_language
}
```

I want to eliminate the `select` call because this should definitely be possible in ActiveRecord. The `select` would be replaced by an additional parameter in the model's `where` query, but I cant figure out how to specify it.

It should look something like this:

```
@translations =
    Translation.includes(:source_phrase, :destination_phrase)
               .where([source_phrase: {language: @source_language},
                       destination_phrase: {language: @destination_language}])
```

However, ActiveRecord thinks (rightfully) that `source_phrase` and `destination_phrase` in the `where` clause are table names. So the table name still has to be `phrases`, but when it is I can't specify the join condition for *both* joins, just the first.

How can I specify 2 separate join conditions on a self-referential association which both access the same attribute on the same model (`language` on the `Phrase` model)?

Comment: Is it possible to query off of Phrases instead of Translations? `Phrase.where(language: "English").joins(:destination_phrases).where({ destination_phrases: { language: "Spanish" } })`

Comment: @LannyBose Indeed I can query the Phrase model, but it's unfortunately not the kind of response I'm looking for - the model I need in the end is a `Translation`. After about two hours of playing around with it, and using something similar to the `join` code that you suggested, I've finally come up with the solution. It also turns out my `Phrase` model associations were not correct (not surprising). I've self-answered, if you want to take a look!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My `Phrase` model turned out to be defined incorrectly, which was the first problem. I've revised it as so:

**Phrase**:

```
class Phrase < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many    :translations,
                class_name: "Translation",
                foreign_key: "source_id"
    has_many    :source_phrases,           # this changed
                through: :translations
    has_many    :inverse_translations,
                class_name: "Translation",
                foreign_key: "destination_id"
    has_many    :destination_phrases,      # this changed
                through: :inverse_translations

    enum language: [:eng, :spa, ...]
end
```

**Translation** has remained the same:

```
class Translation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :source_phrase,
                class_name: "Phrase",
                foreign_key: "source_id"
    belongs_to  :destination_phrase,
                class_name: "Phrase",
                foreign_key: "destination_id"
end
```

Now I am able to perform either of the following queries to get the correct results:

```
Translation
    .includes(:source_phrase => :source_phrases, :destination_phrase => :destination_phrases)
    .where(source_phrases_phrases: {language: 0}, destination_phrases_phrases: {language: 2})
```

or

```
Translation
    .joins(:source_phrase => :source_phrases, :destination_phrase => :destination_phrases)
    .where(source_phrases_phrases: {language: 0}, destination_phrases_phrases: {language: 2})
    .distinct
```

The answer was in specifying the `join`ed association (in this case `source_phrases` and `destination_phrases` in `Phrase`), which could then be used as different table names in the `where` clause.

I should note that I use `source_phrases_phrases` and `destination_phrases_phrases` in the `where` clause because Rails seems to expect the table name (`phrases`) to be appended to the associations (`source_phrases` and `destination_phrases`). It makes for a few ugly queries, but perhaps I could name my associations in the `Phrase` model better...

It also seems that from the `EXPLAIN` output (way too long to put here), the `joins` version is about 25% faster with 6,000 phrases and 12,000 translations. It also exponentially gets faster the larger those tables grow.

Lesson learned? Self-referential associations are a pain. I certainly hope that this helps someone in the future.